# SyntaxError: (unicode error) 'unicodeescape' codec can't decode bytes in position 0-4: truncated \uXXXX escape

Tags: python

I got this error with this code:

```
check = True

while(check):
    print('Login')
    username = input('Username: ')
    print('Password: ')
    print("\\u001\[A", end="")

with open('accounts.csv', 'r') as ac:
    pass
```

I tried to move it one line up but it didnt work. Anyone can help?

Comment: "I tried to move it one line up" -- what does this mean?

Comment: @ScottHunter probably means emit the Move Up ANSI sequence

Comment: The error says you used 3 digits instead of the expected 4. The sequence is wrong too, the ESC character is 1B, not 01. Use `\\u001B` or `\x1b` instead. `print(f"\x1b[31m{message}\x1b[0m")` for example will print the message in red

Answer (score 0):

The error itself says you used 3 digits instead of the expected 4. The code is wrong too - the ESC character is 1B, not 01. You can specify that with `\u001B`, `\033` or `\x1b`.

The sequence is wrong too. To move up you need `ESC [ <N> A` where `<N>` is the number of lines.

For example, this will print a message in green 3 lines above the current cursor line:

```
print("\x1b[3A\x1b[32mBanana\x1b[0m")
```

So will this :

```
print("\u001B[3A\u001B[32mBanana\u001B[0m")
```

and this

```
print("\033[3A\033[32mBanana\033[0m")
```